# Facing this while connecting any new project to firebase in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

> Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

I am facing this error while connecting my new project with Firebase.
I haven't change anything in my my project its a new project and this error is comming while connecting to firebase.

Comment: Have you created the Firebase account and the steps mentioned there to add the json to your project and the changes in the project level and the app level gradle files?

If not, then here is the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup